# How to convert a time to a string

Tags: python, datetime

I am using the date time lib to get the current date. After obtaining the current date I need to convert the obtained date to in to a string format. Any help is appriciated

```
from datetime import date
today=date.today()
print today
```

Comment: So is it date or time you want?

Comment: In the future, please highlight your code snippet in the editor and type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  `print` converts the value to a string as part of printing it.  What more do you want?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `today.strftime(format)`. `format` will be a string as described here http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime . Example:

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
today.strftime("%x")
#>>> '01/31/11'
```

Answer (score 2):

[`datetime.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)  allows you to format a `datetime` however you want

Answer (score 1):

```
stringDate = str(today)
```

If that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Python3, you can use f-string formatting:

```py
from datetime import date 
today=date.today()
today_str = f"{today:%m/%d/%y}"
today_str
#>>>'06/24/22'
```

Comment: In Python 3.6+, to be precise