# Python: How to convert datetime format?

Tags: python, date, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a time to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855406/how-to-convert-a-time-to-a-string)

I have `a` variable as shown in the below code.

```
a = "2011-06-09"
```

Using python, how to convert it to the following format?

```
"Jun 09,2011"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse date and format it using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-and-format-it-using-python) or [Parsing dates and times from strings using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713594/parsing-dates-and-times-from-strings-using-python)

Comment: your quetion related to date format , Heading indicate datetime format, Connfusing!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-06-09', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> d.strftime('%b %d,%Y')
'Jun 09,2011'
```

In pre-2.5 Python, you can replace `datetime.strptime` with `time.strptime`, like so (untested): `datetime.datetime(*(time.strptime('2011-06-09', '%Y-%m-%d')[0:6]))`

Comment: Python 2.4 doesnt have strptime it has only strftime

Answer (score 5):

@Tim's answer only does half the work -- that gets it into a datetime.datetime object.

To get it into the string format you require, you use [datetime.strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
print(datetime.strftime('%b %d,%Y'))
```

Comment: Python 2.4 doesnt have strptime it has only strftime