# How to convert dtype: datetime to dtype: object with Python

Tags: datetime, object, type-conversion, converters

How can I convert datetime object

```
15299   2015-07-27 10:00:00  
Name: date, Length: 15300, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

back to (dtype: object) whatever it's called

```
15299    07/27/2015 10:00:00
Name: date, Length: 15300, dtype: object
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df['date'].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:00:00")

Check this page out for [formatting datetime in python](http://strftime.org/).

Comment: It didn't work. It still shows the dtype is datetime64. I am not trying to change hyphen to slash, I want to change datetime to object.

Comment: @yomoko https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288892/convert-datetime-format