# Date format conversion from yyyy-mm-dd to dd:mm:yyyy

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

How to convert date in Python from `2021-01-11` as `YYYY-MM-DD` to `dd:mm:yyyy` like `11:01:2021`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to convert datetime format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288892/python-how-to-convert-datetime-format)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that in a very simple way with datetime:

```
import datetime

original_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-01-11", '%Y-%m-%d')
formatted_date = original_date.strftime("%d:%m:%Y")
```

[datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change strings to dates and back to string in any format thanks to datetime package.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2021-01-11", "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d:%m:%Y")

## Output
'11:01:2021'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date = "2021-01-11"

lst_date = date.split("-")

new_date = lst_date[2]+":"+lst_date[1]+":"+lst_date[0]
```

Output:

```
11:01:2021
```

Comment: An approach involving strptime/strftime should be preferred since it also validates the input.