# how to write date in different format using datetime module

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

if we want to write the date to a csv it will be written in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format but I want to write in 'dd-mm-yyyy'. how to achieve this.

Write date in different format in datetime module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to convert datetime format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288892/python-how-to-convert-datetime-format)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strftime` function!

It's behaviour is explained in [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) section of documentation.

For your case, the format is as follows:

```py
>>> now = dt.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 30, 9, 37, 54, 218596)
>>> now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
'30-12-2022'
```

Comment: for fetching it is possible I know. but what to do if we want to insert the date(19-12-2000) to a csv using datetime in the same format.