# How do I convert date to Day/Month/Year (20/Jan/2012) in python

Tags: python

I have a script that has been written that I need to change the date on, when the script runs it outputs this message

```
output_messaging("*** DATA REFRESH FOR STREETWORKS DATA EXECUTED ON " + 
    str(datetime.date.today().day) + "/" + str(datetime.date.today().month) + "/" +            
    str(datetime.date.today().year) + " AT " + str(datetime.datetime.now().hour) + ':' +   
    str(datetime.datetime.now().minute) + ':' + str(datetime.datetime.now().second) + " ***\n\n")
```

Which gives

```
*** DATA REFRESH FOR STREETWORKS DATA EXECUTED ON 20/2/2012 AT 18:3 ***
```

I need the date converted to

`20/Feb/2012` , how do i do this?

Comment: Use time.strftime for date formatting. [See this post.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855406/how-to-convert-a-time-to-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strftime` for this -- it's way easier than doing a bunch of custom concatenation. There's a table of formatting conventions [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
>>> s = "*** DATA REFRESH FOR STREETWORKS DATA EXECUTED ON "\
...     "%d/%b/%y AT %H:%M:%S ***\n\n"
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime(s)
'*** DATA REFRESH FOR STREETWORKS DATA EXECUTED ON 28/Feb/12 AT 11:44:03 ***\n\n'
```

As [eumiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9485980/577088)'s answer indicates, you can also invert the above call with a slightly modified format string like so:

```
>>> s = "*** DATA REFRESH FOR STREETWORKS DATA EXECUTED ON "\
...     "{0:%d/%b/%y} AT {0:%H:%M:%S} ***\n\n"
>>> s.format(datetime.datetime.now())
'*** DATA REFRESH FOR STREETWORKS DATA EXECUTED ON 28/Feb/12 AT 13:41:10 ***\n\n'
```

This works because `format` simply calls the (shockingly under-documented) `__format__` method of the `datetime.datetime` object. For example:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().__format__('The current month is %B')
'The current month is February'
```

This works for other types too:

```
>>> (16).__format__('x')
'10'
```

For more on `__format__`, see [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

Comment: Looks like a correct solution so +1 from me. If you suspect someone has been voting inappropriately you can flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @MarkRansom, for what it's worth, I also wondered how eumiro's approach worked. The above is what I figured out with some sleuthing. But I'm surprised at how poorly-documented this part of Python is.

Answer (score 2):

```
output_messaging("*** DATA REFRESH FOR STREETWORKS DATA EXECUTED ON {0:%d/%b/%Y} AT {0:%H:%M} ***".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

prints

```
*** DATA REFRESH FOR STREETWORKS DATA EXECUTED ON 28/Feb/2012 AT 17:41 ***
```

[More information about datetime formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: I'd love to know how the string `format` ends up calling `strftime`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> day = date.today()
>>> day.strftime('%d/%b/%y')
'28/Feb/12'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%b/%Y')
# 28/Feb/2012
```