# Python: Formatting a date in desired pattern

Tags: python-2.7, datetime-format

If the given date pattern is below,

> 2004-7-7

How can I convert this into below pattern,

> 2004-07-07

Using datetime.datetime or some built in function? I don't want to use the replace or string formatting. Does python provide anything (builtin function) to help in such scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a time to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855406/how-to-convert-a-time-to-a-string)

Comment: try [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime` module with [`strptime` and `strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
from datetime import datetime

s = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime('2004-7-7', '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
print(s)

# 2004-07-07
```